# PostgreSQL query including WITH subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

From the following table (named `status`), I need to extract town codes having a status of `'01'` by the end of year 2015. The column `status_date` stores the date at which a town changed its status.

```
gid  | town      | status  | status_date
-----+-----------+---------+-------------
1    | 86001     | 00      | 2000-01-01
2    | 86001     | 01      | 2016-03-01
3    | 86002     | 01      | 2000-01-01
4    | 86003     | 00      | 2000-01-01
5    | 86003     | 01      | 2015-03-01
6    | 86003     | 02      | 2015-09-01
```

I can achieve that with the following query which is a bit long:

```
WITH tab AS (SELECT town, MAX(status_date) FROM status GROUP BY town)

  SELECT 
    t.town

  FROM tab t
    LEFT JOIN status s ON t.town = s.town AND t.max = s.status_date 

  WHERE t.max < '2016-01-01' AND s.status = '01' ;
```

The result is:

```
town   
-------
86002
```

Any idea on how to make this query simpler? Is the `WITH` essential?

---

To create the table for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE status (gid serial NOT NULL, town CHARACTER VARYING(5), status CHARACTER VARYING(2), status_date DATE) ;

INSERT INTO status (town, status, status_date) VALUES
  ('86001', '00', '2000-01-01'),
  ('86001', '01', '2016-03-01'),
  ('86002', '01', '2000-01-01'),
  ('86003', '00', '2000-01-01'),
  ('86003', '01', '2015-03-01'),
  ('86003', '02', '2015-09-01') ;
```

Comment: Your query is not correct, if a town changes from `01` to something else in 2016.

Comment: Towns from 2016 onward are not included in the query anyway. What would be the problem if a town changed its status in 2016?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `distinct on`:

```
select s.*
from (select distinct on (s.town) s.*
      from status s
      where s.status_date < '2016-01-01'
      order by s.town, s.status_date desc
     ) s
where status = '01';
```

This query will get the latest status for each town up to the end of 2015.  The outer query then selects those that are `01`.

Comment: I have just edited you post to add `ASC` and `DESC` order indications, which seem to be necessary for `DISTINCT ON` clause to select the appropriate first row within each set of a town rows. Thanks @Gordon Linoff, this seems a bit more concise than my proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery contains a `GROUP BY` expression, whlist the outer query doesn't. So you have to use a subquery.

You could inline that, but that would only make the query more difficult to read. Your query is as simple as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct - the CTE powered queries are more readable and when built correctly they can offer performance benefits.

Instead of selecting the town in your CTE, select the `gid` column. Then join the original table on it and voila:

```
WITH tab AS (
    SELECT gid, MAX(status_date) 
    FROM status 
    GROUP BY gid 
    HAVING MAX(status_date) < '2016-01-01'
)
SELECT s.whatever
FROM tab t
    INNER JOIN status s ON t.gid = s.sid
WHERE s.status = '01'
```

### EDIT

My apologies; I was in a hurry this morning so I wrote the query wrong. Now I had the time to analyze the problem deeper.

If the performance matters, then work it out around the PK like this.

```
WITH tab AS (
    SELECT MAX(gid) as ID
    FROM [status]
    WHERE YEAR(status_date) = 2015 AND status = '01'
    GROUP BY town
)
SELECT s.*
FROM tab t INNER JOIN status s ON t.ID = s.gid
```

**This only works if the `status_date` grows along with the `gid`.** Else you'll need to fallback to the original query you've posted and max on the date. However you can/should use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`:

```
WITH tab AS (  
    SELECT town, MAX(status_date) as Latest
    FROM [status]
    WHERE YEAR(status_date) = 2015 AND status = '01'
    GROUP BY town
)
SELECT s.*
FROM tab t INNER JOIN [status] s ON t.town = s.town AND t.Latest = s.status_date
```

Comment: What about `DISTINCT ON` suggested by @Gordon Linoff then?

Comment: This is wrong. It includes `86003` which is status 02 at the end of 2015

Comment: You need to join on the `gid` **and** the status_date.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto no, @Gordon Linoff query only returns `86002`! Have a try...

Comment: @wiltomap My comment here refers to this answer not Gordon's answer

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto yep, sorry then!